# R, ggplot - formatting errorbars in theme

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

Hi I have a lot of graphs with errorbars and I'm wondering if there is a way to format them all together in my theme instead of copy and paste each time.

```
mytheme = theme( geom_errorbar.size = 0.8,
                 geom_errorbar.width = 0.1
                 geom_errorbar.position = 0.3 )

# or 

mytheme = theme( geom_errorbar = element_line( size = 0.8, width = 0.1, pd = 0.3 )
```

I've tried registering the information as a new theme element but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In general the `theme` defines the properties of the non-data ink like the axes but will have no effect on the `geom`s. Also, while you could set or override e.g. the default color palettes using e.g. `options(ggplot2.discrete.color = ...)` TBMK there is no such option for `geom`s.

But one option would be to create a custom wrapper function to set your desired defaults like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

geom_errorbar <- function(..., size = .8, width = .1, position = position_dodge(.3)) {
  ggplot2::geom_errorbar(..., size = size, width = width, position = position)
}

df <- data.frame(
  trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
  resp = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
  group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
  upper = c(1.1, 5.3, 3.3, 4.2),
  lower = c(0.8, 4.6, 2.4, 3.6)
)

ggplot(df, aes(trt, resp, colour = group)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper))
```

[image]